# Several foreign keys in a table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

To design my database, I have a big table that contains Devices specifications (table : **"Devices"**), there are about **60** columns.

The value of several features will be in a predefined list (of 3 or 4 values).

They said that we should not have big tables with a lot of columns, and it is necessary to separate the data into small tables. So I did the following:

For a feature that takes a value from a predefined list, I created a small table (2 columns : id & specification) with some lines that will not be update (3 or 4 lines)). Those small tables have the relationship 1 .... n with "Devices" table. There are several specifications of this kind.

Finally, there are several small tables with a **1 ....n** with the "Devices" table.

Question: They said that we should not have big tables with a lot of columns, and it is necessary to separate the data into smaller tables (as I did), but finally I have the same number of columns, because the small tables will migrate foreign keys to the big table (**"Devices"**) !

I need your help, I want to understand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I added normalization to your tags, because that is where the advice to decompose tables comes from.  The issue is not multiple columns in one table.  It's columns that don't belong in the same table, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons:

- it is sometimes easier to manage your data; when a specific value changes, you will only have to change it in one place: 'the small table' and not in many records of 'the big table';
- it may be possible to use data in several places;
- it may take up less space;
- it may be faster;

Are you really not able to reduce the number of columns?

If you show us the table with some example data we can help you better and can give you examples and advise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the first reason : specifications values will not be update for a device. For the 3rd reason : the specifications values (of a device) will not take much space (less than 20 characters). For example for phones specifications : (SIM_card_type, Memory_card_type, Operating_system, Display_technology, chipset, ......)

Comment: When you misspell a value, the 'computer' won't know they are actually the same. 'A small table' reduces the change for such errors, that can occur when you e.g. want to select all devices with a specific SIM_card_type. When you make a form and you have a table with SIM_card_types, you can make (more easily) a combobox with possible values.

Comment: In my case, I have several small tables in relation with "Devices" table. I think that to show all specifications of a device in a single page, the corresponding query will be slow, because there are a lot of joins.

Comment: I don't think you will notice this, databases are very good in joining tables (if properly implemented).

Answer (score 0):

If you end up with a table with too many columns, the thing you must investigate is : how many columns have data that actually is related to any foreign key column, but not directly to the primary ?

Let's make an example, related to "devices":

```
device_id  (PK)
device_type (FK)
vendor_name
vendor_shop_location
```

So you have 4 columns here. One is a Primary Key, one is a foreign key, one should be a foreign key (but it is a regular column), one is related to a column that actually is a foreign key.

That last column, should be in another table, because the third column should be a foreign key.

What they mean with "a table should not have many columns", often - but not always - people are putting foreign key related data in the wrong table. Ask yourself : how many columns in that 60 column table, are foreign keys ? If you have very low, you MAY be in that case. If it is very high, or even all, you have a complex component data structure, possibly righfully so. Hard to tell from here.

Answer (score 0):

The question you should be asking is this:  does the table design reflect the structure of the subject matter in the real world?  You discover the real world subject matter by analyzing it, and analysis comes before design.  A good analysis of the subject matter should yield an ER diagram where the boxes represent entities, the lines between the boxes represent relationships, and the content of the boxes represent attributes.

Do devices really have 60 different attributes, each of which is independent of all the others?  Or are some of these attributes really an attribute of some component of a device, or some such thing as that.  This may lead you to a more normalized table design.  If a truly normalized design yields 60 columns in devices, so be it.

There are design principles that are different from normalizaton, and yield designs that are incompatible with normalized design.  But you should master normalization before you learn when to disregard it.

A second question you may want to ask is whether there are going to be a huge number of NULLS in the device table, because a lot of features are inapplicable to a lot of devices.  If that is the case, and if that's a problem, then you need to ask the question differently.